# c# Linq List add entry

Tags: c#, linq

I have this C# LINQ

```
List<RateRecord> ls = occupancyList.Where(s => s.publish_flag.Contains("0020")).Select(x => new RateRecord()
        {
            RATECODE = x.rate_code.Trim(),
            Occ = new List<RateRecordDtl>() 
            { 
                new RateRecordDtl { date = dateFromShort, pricing = new List<Pricing>() {new Pricing {adults = 2, price = x.rate }} 
            }
        }
        ).ToList();
```

I want to add to the List a second Pricing object **{adults = 1, price = x.rate }**

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Check documentation of _Collection Intializers_ [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: Use a `,` to seperate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a comma and another Pricing object:

```
List<RateRecord> ls = occupancyList.Where(s => s.publish_flag.Contains("0020")).Select(x => new RateRecord()
        {
            RATECODE = x.rate_code.Trim(),
            Occ = new List<RateRecordDtl>() 
            { 
                new RateRecordDtl { date = dateFromShort, pricing = new List<Pricing>() {
                    new Pricing {adults = 2, price = x.rate },
                    new Pricing {adults = 1, price = x.rate }} 
            }
        }
        ).ToList();
```